# Selenium get object url

Tags: python, selenium

In selenium python code i can click to WebElement (e.g `post_raw.click()`)

**Can I identify WebElement link (which will be clicked) with help of selenium methods?**

I know about driver.current_url but I am lookink for link before click. I was looking in documentation, but don't find solution https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

My code example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# login to facebook code
driver.get("https://touch.facebook.com/dota2")

posts_raw = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article")
post_raw = posts_raw[0]
print(type(post_raw)) # <class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>

post_raw.click() # how can I get post_raw link (which was clicked in this line)
```

I want function like this:

```
def get_url_from_WebElement(web_elem: WebElement) -> str:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try get href from xpath.

[image: Question]

**Example** :

I want to get link form "question" so i add `.get_attribute("href")` to `find_element`

```
question_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/h2[1]/a[1]").get_attribute("href")
```

if we print it we get :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371250/selenium-get-object-url
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for general solution. I want function like this:

def get_url_from_WebElement(web_elem: WebElement) -> str:

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a webelement and I want to use that webelement to get the a tag. This does not get the element clicked which is just the middle of the web_element generally.

```
def get_url_from_WebElement(web_element):
    try:
        elem=web_element.find_element(BY.XPATH,".//a").get_attribute("href")
        return elem
    except:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
def get_url_from_webelement(xpath):
    the_url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "\"" + xpath + "\"").get_attribute("href")
    return the_url
```